# pandas dataframe get the value with most occurence per row (Python2)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, data-munging

I have the dataframe

```
df =A B B A B
    B B B B A
    A A A B B
    A A B A A
```

And I want to get a vector with the element the appeared the most, per row.
So here I will get `[B,B,A,A]`

What is the best way to do it? In Python2

Answer (score 1):

Let us using `mode`

```
df.T.mode()
   0  1  2  3
0  B  B  A  A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your vector `v` with most appearing values with

`v = [_[1].value_counts().idxmax() for _ in df.iterrows()]`.

Be careful when you have multiple elements that occur the most.